# SQL integrity constraint error in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

currently working with laravel 5.6 and having trouble with updating the form i created.

the full error is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: update `companies` set `name` = , `description` = this is a SE company., `updated_at` = 2018-12-16 10:05:55 where `id` = 1)
```

edit.blade.php file follows:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('companies.update',[$company->id]) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company-name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="Enter name"
                   id="company-name"
                   required
                   name="description"
                   spellcheck="false"
                   class="form-control"
                   value="{{ $company->name }}"
            />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company-content">Description</label>
            <textarea placeholder="Enter description"
                        style="resize:vertical"
                        name="description" 
                        id="company-content" 
                        rows="5" cols="5"
                        spellcheck="false"
                        class="form-control autosize-target text-left">
                        {{ $company->description}}
                    </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                    value="Submit"/>
        </div>

      </form>
```

this is the migration file:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->longText('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show that part in your PHP where you are processing this form? It might be part of the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note that I will update my answer as soon as your PHP code snippet is included, since that might be part of the reason of your error.)

You used the wrong name attribute in your input element. You are checking twice for `description` now.

Change this:

```
<input placeholder="Enter name"
                   id="company-name"
                   required
                   name="description"
                   spellcheck="false"
                   class="form-control"
                   value="{{ $company->name }}"
            />
```

To this:

```
<input placeholder="Enter name"
                   id="company-name"
                   required
                   name="name"
                   spellcheck="false"
                   class="form-control"
                   value="{{ $company->name }}"
            />
```

Comment: Your'e welcome! Can you please accept and upvote my answer in that case? :) That's how Stack Overflow works: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Virginia i'm sorry i can't upvoting becoz i don't have 15 reputations yet

Comment: No worries, just accepting the answer is good too, because this will help other programmers with the same problem :) Thank you for accepting!

Answer (score 0):

Your input attribute name is not correct

```
<input placeholder="Enter name"
               id="company-name"
               required
               name="description" <!-- <<-- This should be "name" not "description" -->
               spellcheck="false"
               class="form-control"
               value="{{ $company->name }}"
/>
```

And if for some reason you want name to be nullable

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ...   
        $table->string('name')->nullable(); // <<-- this is modified
        // ...
    });
}
```